# Can System.setProperty be used per request?

Tags: java

I have a requirement to set the different system property per each request to REST API.
Can `System.setProperty("filePath", file.getAbsolutePath());` be used? is it thread safe? Will it override old value with new value when multiple/latest request comes to server before the current request is processed?

Comment: If it's per request, why would you want to set it at system level?

Comment: Why would you do that ... this is so unclear

Comment: i need to build a DefaultConfigurationBuilder which needs a configuration file where configuration file has this - fileName="${sys:filePath}" - filePath is dynamic and changes per each request. @Federico klez Culloca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, environment variables will be overrided by each `System.setProperty` method call.

If you don't need to override there are plenty of solutions:

1. Use servlet container context to store each request's file path
2. Use [Java ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to manually store the property. But keep attention that you have to clean it up after request ends.

Answer (score 0):

That very much depends on your exact setup. This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626100/is-there-a-way-to-pass-application-specific-properties-in-websphere) suggests for example that you can set different system properties in different websphere containers.

So, if you have such a setup, **and** if you can guarantee that only **one** client is using one endpoint at a time, this would theoretically be possible.

But the chain of *if*s tells us the real answer: forget this idea. System properties aren't **intended** t be used like this!

If different users of that REST service need "one detail" to be different compared to other runs, then that absolutely implies: that needs to be a **parameter** that the clients pass to the server when invoking that REST service.

---